# MVC3 javascript image issue

Tags: javascript, image, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a C#.Net MVC3 web app.  In a certain js file I am loading a dialog box and assigning the loading: property the below image

```
loading: $('<img src="../../Content/Images/loading.gif" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">'),
```

However, in different environments it does not find the image.  The code in those instances should be

```
loading: $('<img src="../../../Content/Images/loading.gif" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">'),
```

I tried

```
loading: $('<img src="@Href("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">'),
```

And also tried

```
loading: $('<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">'),
```

Neither worked....when I've used @Url.Content and @Href in the aspx files, it works.

Needless to say, I'm not a javaScript expert, but I figure this must be do-able in the js file.

Any ideas?

Comment: The @url.Content should work. Did you debug with firebug?

Comment: Can you show some more code? Its not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can't use .NET code in the JS file as it is not processed by .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I usually get around this is by creating a helper function in your master or layout page:

Place this in your layout page below the reference to jquery but above any other file that will use it:

```
// This adds the helper onto the jQuery object rather than just being global
$.getUrl = function (path) {
     return '@Url.Content("~")' + path;
};
```

Then use it like this in your js file:

```
$('<img src="' + $.getUrl('/Content/Images/loading.gif') + '" />')
```

Answer (score 2):

As Richard D stated you cannot run .NET code in a javascript file. A possible workaround is to stored the image path in a hidden field in your View and then get it from the javascript file.

View file:

```
<input type="hidden" id="image-path" value="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")" />
```

JS file:

```
var imagePath = $("#image-path").val();
loading: $('<img src="' + imagePath + '" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">'),
```

Comment: and RichardD...thanks.  That's kind of what I thought.  I'll try the above idea and let you know how it goes.  thanks!